# How does Weebly work?

Tags: web-server

I have used Weebly in the past (not anymore). When made a new subdomain in there, it was all instant and good and stuff and you know and whatever. I understand how they're secure (Wildcard Certificates), but what I don't understand is how they server my subdomain so quickly. In my experience, every time I made new subdomain, I needed to restart the server (Apache). But how does Weebly restart their server without the website being affected overall? Does it restart every time a new subdomain is created? Or, is there a method that doesn't require the server to restart?

Basically, how do websites that create subdomains for you work (server-wise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are likely using a [wildcard subdomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) (`*.example.com`) and possibly a corresponding [wildcard SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) as well.

Comment: I’m well aware of that. My question, though, was on how the server applies the new subdomains to the webserver without affecting the website. Meaning, current logins, ongoing website edits, etc.

Comment: @CB49 `*.example.com` points all requests to the same set of code, which'll do database lookups etc. based off the hostname to get the right data. No restarts - graceful or otherwise - are necessary.

Comment: Oh... This also makes more sense and seems easier. Wow... Never thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: I’d actually aprecciate it if you add that part to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of services/daemons/servers can be asked to re-load the configuration, without requiring a restart.

[Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/stopping.html):

- systemctl reload apache   # replace apache with apache2, http or httpd
- service apache graceful # replace apache with apache2, http or httpd
- apachectl -k graceful
- pkill -SIGUSR1 apache  # replace apache with apache2 or httpd
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270108/how-to-reload-apache-configuration-for-a-site-without-restarting-apache

[Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control):

- nginx -s reload
- service nginx reload
- systemctl reload nginx

Comment: Cool! I was unaware that a reload did not abort current connections. Thanks!

Comment: @CB49 This is *extremely* unlikely to be how Weebly works.

Comment: Guess so. Would using this method apply more stress to the server?

Comment: Yes, but you should not worry much about the increased load. If you website is too affected about a reload, than it means that you need to scale it out horizontally. Add a load-ballancer, add other web servers to serve part of the requests.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici A system like Weebly is likely to have dozens, hundreds, or thousands of servers, and new subdomains many times an hour. I'd **definitely** worry about server load in *that* scenario - it'd be fairly constant.